# Is CommonJS a standard that can be piggybacked on or is it just another JavaScript module system?

Tags: javascript, module, commonjs

Wikipedia states this about CommonJS:

> [CommonJS] is a project with the goal of specifying an ecosystem for
>   JavaScript outside the browser

I understand that this means that CommonJS is a system that's intended to be agnostic as to the platform that ES is being used on.  Does that mean that when used in the context of a web browser that it's essentially just another big polyfill (like SystemJS), for the ES module system? Or is it something that sits underneath a module system like SystemJS or WebPack that renders that system platform agnostic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike SystemJS, CommonJS itself is a [specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1), not a module loader. It is platform agnostic in that it relies on core ECMAScript 5 syntax/features; it specifies a set of fields to define - `module.exports` - and method to read them - `require` - to facilitate better code organization. It might be thought of as an unofficial precursor to ES6 module syntax. AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition) is a competing unofficial standard, [forked from CommonJS](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md#relation-to-commonjs-) and implemented by Require.js.

Likely as it is unofficial, browsers don't include any native support for CommonJS modules, and usage requires some kind of module loader implementing support for CommonJS (like Browserify). Node.js implements the CommonJS specification, but even it [wraps its module executions](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) in a function at run-time.

CommonJS is among the earlier patterns ([described](https://www.blueskyonmars.com/2010/01/29/commonjs-the-first-year/) as  "a grass roots effort", as opposed to an official ECMAScript spec addition) intended to account for JavaScript's lack of code organization. According to the [project's website](http://www.commonjs.org/history/)) it was created in 2009, around the same time Node.js was [originally released](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/tags?after=v0.0.4), and intended to provided module structure for non-browser execution environments (although it could easily apply to browsers where mega-scripts and globals are just as problematic). The project was founded as result of [this blog post](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/2009/01/29/what-server-side-javascript-needs/).

So to answer your title question, it is an unofficial standard that will be obsolete when ES6 modules are (nearly) universally supported.

Comment: Thanks Greg, so can SystemJS or WebPack theoretically call into CommonJS? Likewise can they utilise AMD since overall that's being preferred now?

Comment: The docs for SystemJS and Webpack both state they support both CommonJS and AMD, with both transpiling them into their final respective format for production.